# Veracode flaw: URL Redirection to Untrusted Site ('Open Redirect'). CWE ID: 601

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, response.redirect, veracode

This is the method I've written and validating the URL. But the flaw still persists in both the lines of Response.Redirect();

```
public static string GetValidLocalUrl(string url)
        {
            bool isLocal = false;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                 isLocal = !url.StartsWith("http:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                               && !url.StartsWith("https:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                               && Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Relative);
            }

            if (isLocal)
                return url;
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }


if (Request.QueryString["selectedPersonID"] == null )
        Response.Redirect(Functions.GetValidLocalUrl("RecordEnhancement.aspx?recordID=" + qRecord.concatRecordID + "&selectedWorkplaceID=" + WorkplaceID));
    else
        Page.Response.Redirect(Functions.GetValidLocalUrl("RecordEnhancement.aspx?recordID=" + qRecord.concatRecordID + "&selectedWorkplaceID=" + WorkplaceID+ "&selectedPersonID=" + Request.QueryString["selectedPersonID"]));
```

The scan is still throwing the flaw at

```
Response.Redirect(Functions.GetValidLocalUrl("RecordEnhancement.aspx?recordID=" + qRecord.concatRecordID + "&selectedWorkplaceID=" + WorkplaceID));

Page.Response.Redirect(Functions.GetValidLocalUrl("RecordEnhancement.aspx?recordID=" + qRecord.concatRecordID + "&selectedWorkplaceID=" + WorkplaceID+ "&selectedPersonID=" + Request.QueryString["selectedPersonID"]));
```

Comment: Hi @vangelis Pablo, I am also facing the same issue, were you able to resolve the flaw?

Comment: Yes. The issue is resolved. I've actually written a function validating the redirect URL with all the possible existing domains in the website. On top of it I've used com.veracode.annotation.RedirectURLCleanser.

https://help.veracode.com/reader/DGHxSJy3Gn3gtuSIN2jkRQ/xrEjru~XmUHpO6~0FSae2Q

Comment: Hi @VangelisPablo could you share example of such a validating function?

Comment: @ravenik , I cannot share the example. But I'll tell you I did it. We had a database and we stored all the possible domain names for eg: stackoverflow.com, facebook.com, xyz.com and validated it before Response.Redirect. Validation : Get all the domains from database and check whether the redirection domain exists in the your stored domains, then redirect it or else send a default page.